# How do make this triangle into a quad without breaking edge loops?

Tags: modeling, topology

I've got a problem with topology and im feeling stuck. I can't break up the triangle into a quad without breaking the edge loops.

On creation, edge loops go everywhere once I make a quad out of it thanks to the n-pole I got (that was meant to be a bent wall - first I added loops to the face to bend it and then added loops on the cube and connected them).

How do I get rid of the triangle properly?

[image: original triangle]

[image: split it into quads, connected to extra loops -> edgeloops going bad..]

Comment: Just subdivide in half the upper edges on both side.

Comment: Im confused, which ones? We're talking about the triangle on the first screenshot, right? Don't you get an ngon as the result?